# how to change the default lib path in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

for example, there is path

/www/node/node_project/public/lib

I want to move /public/lib to /lib, but keep the node_project running; since /lib folder are share front-end libraries with other project (PHP projects maybe); so how can I move the lib folder around?!

Comment: app.use(express.static('lib'));

Comment: Are you using express as a static web-server? I mean are you serving files from /www/node/node_project/public/lib folder?

Comment: @NidhinDavid I was trying to use /www/lib as my /node/node_project library path, so I can share the lib folder with many node_projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Express static root folder as:

```
var app = require('express')();
var port = 3000 //The port on which your server listens
app.use(express.static('path to lib folder');
app.listen(port);
```

If you want to specify a route specific to the lib folder then you can set it as `app.use(express.static('/your/route', path to lib folder');`

If your lib folder is **on the same folder** as the file that initializes express then you can simply give `app.use(express.static('lib');`

If your **lib folder is a sub-folder** of the folder in which express is initialized then you can use `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'path to lib');`

If your lib folder is on **any other location** then specify the absolute path to the lib folder like `app.use(express.static('path to lib from /');`

Comment: Yes, the solution works, but there is something different which might due to the version differences. I'm using Express 4.x, so the better answer would be: app.use('/lib', express.static(path.resolve('../lib')));